# Marshalling Map to Object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am using Jackson to marshal json calls to a web application and I am trying to design a method that will accept a number of different objects.

For example:

I have two class structures

```
{
    name:"Joe",
    surname:"Bloggs"
}
```

Corresponds to the java class Person

```
{
    address1:"21 Main st",
    city:"Georgetown",
    zip:"12345"
}
```

Corresponds to the java class address

Now I want to make a call that can handle either of those classes in such a way:

```
 {
      type:"Person",
      data:{
         name:"Joe",
         surname:"Bloggs"
      }
 }
```

I can create a call that marshals the above request to a Map or I can create two separate requests, one for each object structure and marshal them directly into the corresponding classes.

Is it possible to use Jackson to marshal the above request to a Map and then, after reading part of the map --e.g. map.get("type")-- use Jackson to marshal a sub-object --e.g. map.get("data")-- into the corresponding java class without reconverting back to json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jackson polymorphism. Here is an easy example:

```
public class Polymorphism3Main {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(generatePerson());
        System.out.println("json = " + json);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Request.class));

        json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(generateAddress());
        System.out.println("json = " + json);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Request.class));
    }

    private static Person generatePerson() {
        Person result = new Person();
        result.setName("name");
        result.setSurname("surname");
        return result;
    }

    private static Address generateAddress() {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddress1("address 1");
        address.setCity("city");
        address.setZip("324212");
        return address;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Person.class, name = "person"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Address.class, name = "address")
})
interface Request {
}

class Person implements Request {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}

class Address implements Request {
    private String address1;
    private String city;
    private String zip;
}
```

That code will produce slightly different json but it is still sutable:

```
{"person":{"name":"name","surname":"surname"}}
{"address":{"address1":"address 1","city":"city","zip":"324212"}}
```

If you want to have exactly the same json format as you posted -- you will need to create a wrapper object.

In general I would recommend to create two separate method to handle these two requests differently. In that case you code will be more clean and you don't need to combine Person with Address through Request interface.

Comment: Yes, writing two different requests is the approach I am taking now. My problem is that I end up with load of different functions to handle objects that are different in structure, but which share business logic in the way I need to process them. If you do this for two objects it is ok, but if you have tens of objects, for which you have to do, say four similar operations for each (e.g. create, update, delete, list), you end up with 40 similar methods, instead of four. Unfortunately having a common inheritance would be too much of an overhead in this situation.